# How to check if memory has been initialized?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a way of checking if memory pointed to by pointer has been initialized?(not necessarily by my program).
Thanks

Comment: What's your test for "initialized"?  All zeroes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Uninitialized memory can contain *anything*, including bytes that make it look like it has been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to define a "not initialized value", such as 0x0 (just because), and use that inside your application, setting all the memory you ask for with that value.

In general, no, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

By "initialized" you probably mean "allocated". In any case: **no**, it isn't possible.

If the pointer is NULL, you can say it wasn't initialized for sure, however :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You might be able to do something low-level and OS-specific, like see if touching the memory generates a page fault, but I can't believe that anyone would seriously contemplate doing something like this when there must be a better overall solution.